# Tengo este error y no se como arreglarlo ni porque se genera---> Error al conectar a la base de datos: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

El problema según entiendo es que se termina el tiempo de conexión por lo que se cierra y tengo que volver a abrir pero el tiempo que me deja conectar no pasa de 1 minuto lo cual me da un gran problema porque tengo otro proyecto que es un registro el cual debe conectarse a este código para hacer una inserción a la base de datos que tengo en el servidor. No se si el problema es del servidor o del código, si alguien puede explicarme que genera este problema y como solucionarlo.

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'dtai.uteq.edu.mx',
  user: '****',
  password: '***',
  database: '****',
});

db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error al conectar a la base de datos: ' + err.message);
  } else {
    console.log('Conexión exitosa a la base de datos.');
  }
});

app.post('/insertarUsuario', (req, res) => {
  const { id, nombre, correo, pass } = req.body;
  const sql = 'INSERT INTO usuario (id, nombre, correo, pass, tipo) VALUES (0, ?, ?, ?, 0)';
  const values = [id, nombre, correo, pass];
 
  db.query(sql, values, (error, results) => {
     if (error) {
       console.error('Error al insertar usuario: ' + error.message);
       res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al insertar usuario' });
     } else {
       console.log('Usuario insertado correctamente.');
       res.json({ message: 'Usuario insertado correctamente.' });
     }
  });
 });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor en ejecución en el puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: La conexión a la base de datos debe de ser asíncrona.